# Difference between two dates - Cannot Convert type 'int?' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Tags: c#, linq, timespan

I'm trying to get the difference between two dates, but I get this error:

> Cannot Convert type 'int?' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Then I tried to use `Convert.ToInt32()` or `Int32.Parse()`, but still had the same error.
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction?

ViewModel:

```
 public class RMACLOSE
 {
     public TimeSpan? diff { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller:

```
var list = from RH in RMA_History
select new RMACLOSE 
{
    // Cannot Convert type 'int?' to 'System.TimeSpan?'
    diff = DbFunctions.DiffDays(RH.EndDate, RH.StartDate) 
}
```

`RH.EndDate` (`DateTime`): 2018-11-15 12:15:00.000 
`RH.StartDate` (`DateTime`): 2018-05-24 15:43:00.000

Difference : 175 days

Comment: It's complaining that you're giving it an `int?` when it wants a `TimeSpan?`. Why would you think methods that *produce* an `int` would be part of the solution here? Your problem is you have too many of those to start with.

Comment: could you please show how your data look like in `RH.EndDate, RH.StartDate`

Comment: You have literally shown *everything except the most pertinent parts of the code*.

Comment: @er-mfahhgk i updated my question :)

Comment: I think you need the difference between both date and i.e. `175` so why you could not use `int?` type of `diff` property inside `RMACLOSE` class so might be your error becomes solved and then you don't need any type casting

Comment: @er-mfahhgk thanks mate it works :) and i deserved -2 down vote :) i understand why! if you dont mind post answer i will mark as right answer

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you were right :)

Comment: @TheFirst, answer added, and upvoted to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the difference between both date means `EndDate` and `StartDate` and i.e. `175`,

So why you could not use `int?` type of `diff` property inside `RMACLOSE` class like

```
public class RMACLOSE
{
    public int? diff { get; set; }
}
```

And might be your error becomes solved and then you don't need any type casting and you simply use your LINQ query as it is like

```
select new RMACLOSE 
{    
  diff = DbFunctions.DiffDays(RH.EndDate, RH.StartDate)   
}
```

`DbFunctions.DiffDays` returns `int?` so it matches your `diff` property type and then no error will remain.

Answer (score 1):

It is evident from the error message that `DbFunctions.DiffDays()` returns an `int?` (that presumably represents the time difference in days).

Therefore you will need to do something like this to convert it into `TimeSpan?`:

```
var days = DbFunctions.DiffDays();

if (days != null)
    diff = TimeSpan.FromDays(days.Value);
else
    diff = null;
```